# How to convert multiple rows data in table into single row which was extrcated through OCD?

Tags: python, pandas, ocr

I have a PDF (attached) and it is converted into .txt using OCR. The OCR output looks as

```
'2 VERFEN 100MCG NO11909 - Verve AMPO 1.00 47.70 0.00 47.70 47.70\n',

 'INJECTION 2ML 28/02/202 ULE\n',

 '(FENTANYL) 2 HEGCUNIE\n',

 'VERVE\n',

 '3 ADRENOR 4MG INABA294 AMPO 2.00 112.88 0.00 112.88 112.88\n',

 'INJECTION 2ML oe ULE\n',

 '(NORADRENALINE 31/08/202 HEGORINIE\n',

 ') SAMARTH 1\n',

 '4 CELHEP; 50001U; HP11941A Celon NOS 3.00 267.00 0.00 267.00 267.00\n',

 'INJECTION; \n',

 '(HEPARIN); 30/06/202 HEGGUNJE\n',

 'CELON 2\n',
```

[image]

And I need the output in this format

```
'2 VERFEN 100MCG INJECTION 2ML (FENTANYL) VERVE NO11909 - 28/02/2021 Verve AMPO ULE 1.00 47.70 0.00 47.70 47.70\n',


'3 ADRENOR 4MG INJECTION 2ML (NORADRENALINE) SAMARTH   INABA2942 -31/08/202 AMPO ULE 2.00 112.88 0.00 112.88 112.88\n',


'4 CELHEP; 50001U; INJECTION; (HEPARIN);  CELON   HP11941A 30/06/2022 Celon NOS 3.00 267.00 0.00 267.00 267.00\n',
```

Eventually, I need to retain table format information.

Comment: It is not as simple as it seems. You need structural data like the coordinates of each word and apply a clustering algorithm for getting the above output.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an optimized solution.

If the first character of each line in the desired output should **always** be a number followed by whitespace then your problem can be broken down to identifying the pattern and then writing code to concatenate the lines till the next pattern.

The regex to identify the number at the beginning of string is `^'[0-9]{2,3,4}`

The regex will look for one, two, three or four digit numbers. Note the whitespace after `}` which ensures that we are looking at correct pattern. This regex will work for

```
'2 VERFEN 100MCG NO11909 - Verve AMPO 1.00 47.70 0.00 47.70 47.70\n',
'INJECTION 2ML 28/02/202 ULE\n',
'(FENTANYL) 2 HEGCUNIE\n',
'VERVE\n'
```

but not for

```
'2 VERFEN 100MCG NO11909 - Verve AMPO 1.00 47.70 0.00 47.70 47.70\n',
'INJECTION 2ML 28/02/202 ULE\n',
'(FENTANYL) \n',
'2 HEGCUNIE\n',
'VERVE\n'
```

The two **2**s will be treated separately.

Your logic in the code maybe something like below -

1. Declare temporary string variable
2. Do the 3 to 5 till end of file
3. Read each line in file
4. If pattern match in line **then** 1. write the temporary string variable in **new** file, 2. clear the temporary string variable.
5. Remove the `\n,'` from end and concatenate the line to temporary string variable

You may want to handle first write into the file if you do not want the first line as blank.